# Manually installing a software library in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, software-installation

I want to install an open-source code(REEF3D) in ubuntu 18.04. To increase the computational efficiency during running the code, I have to install HYPRE( high performance preconditions) which will help parallel iteration solution. HYPRE requires MPI to be installed first. So I installed openmpi and went well. I downloaded hypre-2.11.2.2.tar.gz (latest version), copy to the home directory, unzipped it there and navigated to the directory src within hypre-2.11.2. (I followed this from the manual of the code.) However, when I tried to configure using the command line ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/hypre, I got the following message:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu 
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu 
checking for mpxlc... no 
checking for mpixlc... no 
checking for mpiicc... no 
checking for mpicc... mpicc 
checking for mpxlC... no 
checking for mpixlcxx... no 
checking for mpiicpc... no 
checking for mpiCC... mpiCC 
checking for mpxlf... no 
checking for mpixlf77... no 
checking for mpiifort... no 
checking for mpif77... mpif77 
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes 
checking for ranlib... ranlib 
checking whether the C compiler works... yes 
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out 
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no 
checking for suffix of object files... o 
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes 
checking whether mpicc accepts -g... yes 
checking for mpicc option to accept ISO C89... none needed 
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes 
checking whether mpiCC accepts -g... yes 
checking whether we are using the GNU Fortran compiler... yes 
checking whether mpif77 accepts -g... yes 
checking how to get verbose linking output from mpif77... -v
```

Note that I have already installed `gcc`, `g++` and `gfortran` compilers.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What was wrong with installation of `libhypre-dev` package from the [official repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=HYPRE)?

Comment: Do you have a specific question about the message?

Comment: @ N0rbert I did, but I don't know where to find the configuration file. As I mentioned above the configuration file when I tried to install manually is within the "src" directory. Any way to configure it?

Comment: @  steeldriver. I do not why it says                                                           "checking for mpxlc... no 
checking for mpixlc... no 
checking for mpiicc... no                                                                                            Because after getting these results, it gave me error messages whe I tried to compile.